# Conflicting file streams when writing to single text file

Tags: c#, filestream

I have three buttons Header/body/footer.MY header has space of 1983 at the end of line and then my body starts at 1984 when i save my body first while exporting to text file it copies fine but when i click on header to append the file half of the data is replaced by space from  header.how can i save my body first and then  while appending the header it pushes the body downwards  is it possible.

My Header:

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\Users\IT-Administrator\Desktop\ee.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
fs.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
//sw.WriteLine(comboBox7.Text +comboBox2.Text +textBox6.Text);
sw.WriteLine("{0}{1}{2}{3,-1983}", comboBox7.Text, comboBox2.Text,textBox6.Text, ' ');
sw.Close();
fs.Close();
```

My Body Button:

```
if (myDataset == null)
{
    return;
}

if (myDataset.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 0)
{
    return;
}

DataView vwExport = new DataView(myDataset.Tables[0]);
SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
sfd.Filter = "TXT file|*.txt";
sfd.FileName = "ticket_info "  + ".txt";

if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    if (sfd.FileName != "")
    {
        ExportDatatviewToCsv(sfd.FileName, vwExport);
        MessageBox.Show("File has been saved as: " + Environment.NewLine + sfd.FileName + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + "NB: This dataset has been ordered by t_reference in ascending order. If being combined with an existing dataset - that dataset will also need to be sorted in this way.", "Operation complete", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }
}
```

Comment: If i understand you. You want to save text to a file. By saving the body at the beginnning of the file because nothing in it yet, and you save the header you want the header to be appende before the body? That is all you need?

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is:

1. write the body to the file and save it;
2. write the header to an temporary file (preferably in memory);
3. read contents of the file with the body in it (opening in readwrite mdoe) add that to the tempfile;
4. overwrite the contents of the body in the file with the joined data from the memory stream.

This is the easiest way to prepend to a file.
I hope this helps you.

Regards, Jordy

Comment: And what if the body is let's say, 100 MB? Reading the entire file in memory isn't very efficient.